# Is the answer to the question "How many moments in time exist between any two particular moments?", infinitely many?

Tags: time, relativity, discrete

This question is related to Xeno's paradox, and to the discrete/continuous time debate, but it comes from a slightly different angle.

If the answer is infinitely many, why would this not be a contradiction of the law of conservation of information, in that each of the infinite moments could be said to contain different coordinate information regarding the position of any moving object which would mean the universe contains uncomputable infinite information?

Also, doesn't the truth of relativistic curved spacetime making clocks tick differently in different parts of space mean that the divisibility of time passing changes where effected by gravity, i.e. it isn't infinite everywhere?

Comment: More on [Zeno's paradox](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+*eno+paradox).

Answer (score 1):

> If the answer is infinitely many, why would this not be a contradiction of the law of conservation of information, in that each of the infinite moments could be said to contain different coordinate information regarding the position of any moving object which would mean the universe contains uncomputable infinite information?

This is not at all what the conservation of information means.

The conservation of information means that if you have some system described by some phase space and then you consider all of the states within some volume of the phase space, then if you propagate all of those states for any fixed amount of time you will find that the resulting states occupy the same volume of phase space.

It has nothing whatsoever to do with the number of states within the volume nor the number of instants of time over which the states propagate through phase space.